# laravel 5.4 Пытаюсь получить create_at из бд mssql через eloquent, но получаю неправильную дату

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, querybuilder

Пытаюсь получить таким образом данные по модели из базы данных:

```
$logs = Carriers_log::on($bd)->orderBy('id_log', 'desc')->get();

foreach ($logs as $log){
echo $log->created_at;
}
```

Но поле "created_at" выводится не правильное:

В базе - 2019-03-14 15:41:33.000
Выводится - 2020-02-03 15:09:34

Не могу понять в чём дело, раньше выводилось правильно, в базу записывается всё правильно и если проверить массив...

```
dd($log);
```

То там будет правильное значение:

```
"created_at" => "2019-03-14 15:46:00.000"
"updated_at" => "2019-03-14 15:46:00.000"
```

Но как только пытаюсь уточнить поле даты, оно сразу меняется.

Ещё пробовал получить так значение:

```
$log->value('created_at')
```

Получаю такой ответ, год правильный, остальное - нет.

```
date: 2019-04-03 11:21:50.0 Asia/Yakutsk (+09:00)
```

Есть идеи что могло случиться? На сервере время правильное.

Код модели:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Carriers_log extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'carriers_log';//таблица модели

    public $primaryKey = 'id_log';

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-d-m H:i:s.000';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'log_title', 'log_body'];

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Понял что формат данных не правильный Y-d-m, а в базе Y-m-d, если сделать как в базе, выводит на экран правильно, но тогда ошибка при вставке в базу, что значение вышло за пределы диапазона. Странность в том, что даже с неправильным форматов в базу пишется как надо.

P.S Сохранение через модель

```
$log = new Carriers_log;
$log->create(['user_id' => 1, 'log_title' => 'ПЕРЕХОД ПО ССЫЛКЕ',
            'log_body' => $request->url()]);
```

Comment: предоставьте полный код вашей модели Carriers_log

Comment: @P.Fateev , я добавил код модели

Comment: Зачем вы указываете в модели `protected $dateFormat = 'Y-d-m H:i:s.000';` ? попробуйте убрать эту строку

Comment: @P.Fateev без неё не хочет сохранять в базу и я получаю ошибку:
SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Преобразование типа данных nvarchar в тип данных datetime привело к выходу значения за пределы диапазона.

Comment: значит, неправильно сохраняете. можете показать код, который сохраняет?

Comment: @P.Fateev добавил код сохранения выше